# Replace the brake servo at 51k?

Tags: brakes, infiniti, g37

Vehicle: Infiniti G37 coupe 2008

Diagnosis: Some times I hear whistling coming from left part and brakes gets hard

- Is it normal to change the brake servo at 51,500 miles?
- What is the possibility to repair it instead of changing it?
- Should change all related parts with it? or just the servo it self?

Comment: I've cleaned up the question as best I could. If I've misrepresented something, please let me know. When you say "servo" are you talking about the brake booster (vacuum actuated part) or the master cylinder (hydraulic portion)? When you say about the "whistling coming from left part" ... are you talking about the servo? Or what exactly? What other diagnostics have you done?

Comment: No, I don't really believe it is common in well-designed cars to replace brake servo at 51,500 miles. However, about your car I cannot say, because I've never owned such a vehicle. Many cars have common issues. Perhaps somebody posting an answer could find out if braking system related problems are common in this vehicle. Generally, if the hourly cost of labor is high, repairs aren't worth it and components are replaced instead. A DIY mechanic with lots of spare time could do repairs, but then again remember you're working with the brake system that is safety critical.

Answer (score 1):

A whistling sound implies an air or vacuum leak. With the break servo it will be a vacuum leak. A servo failure at < 100,000 miles seems quite unusual. Be sure to check that the leak is from the servo and not from the vacuum hose serving it. I'm much more suspicious of the hose than of the servo unit.